Jews crying when getting Arayot mitzvah
Rambam in Hilchot Issurei Biah writes that when the Jews got the commandments regarding all the forbidden relationships, they cried. Where does he get this from?

See Bavli Yoma 75a

Now you tell us where Rambam says that

@DoubleAA https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%97

Rambam & sources from Chazal can be found here: https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Full/Issurei_Biah/22/18#e0n6

Thank you all. If someone wants to write up an answer I’ll mark it
